# Subset of numbers analogous to primitive polynomials over finite fields

Tags: finite-fields, analytic-number-theory

It is well known that many problems in number theory have an analogue on the ring of polynomials over finite fields and vice versa, the primes in $\mathbb{F}_q[x]$ being the irreducible polynomials. For instance, the number of primes up to $x$ is $\sim x/ \log x$ by the Prime Number Theorem, while the number of irreducible polynomials of degree $n$ over $\mathbb{F}_q$ is $\sim q^n/n$. Note this is $N/ \log_q N$, where $N$ is the number of monic polynomials of degree $n$ over $\mathbb{F}_q$.

I wonder what are, if any, the numbers which are analogous to primitive polynomials (irreducibles of degree $n$ whose roots are primitive elements in $\mathbb{F}_{q^n}$) over finite fields?

Since the number of primitive polynomials of degree $n$ over $\mathbb{F}_q$ is $\phi(q^n-1)/n$, I suspect that the amount of such numbers below $x$ is $\phi(x)/ \log x = \dfrac{\phi(x)}{x} \dfrac{x}{\log x}$ if we assume that $x \in \mathbb{N}$. Note the $x / \log x$ of the PNT while $\phi(x)/x$ is the proportion of integers below $x$ which are coprime to $x$. Thanks!

Comment: A problem in a literal interpretation of you question is that the values of the Euler totient function $\phi$ jump around, but this kind of *cumulative* functions (such as $\pi(x)$) are monotonically increasing. There are natural substitutes to questions about primitive polynomials in $\Bbb{F}_q[x]$ and/or primitive roots modulo priimes in $\Bbb{Z}_p$, but I'm too ignorant to say much. Undoubtedly you know about Artin's primitive root conjecture and the analogues in $\Bbb{F}_q[x]$ due to Bilharz.

Comment: (cont'd) Chapter 10 in [Michael Rosen's book](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387953359) discusses this. Don't ask me to describe the key ideas. I'm sad to say I skipped that chapter, because I was in a hurry to get to a later one. The focus in Artin's conjecture / Bilharz' theorem is different from yours (they fix the number/polynomial, and ask how often that is a generator modulo a prime/irreducible polynomial).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The focus is indeed different; I wasn't considering generators modulo irreducibles, but irreducible polynomials of degree $n$ with roots of order $q^n-1$ which therefore generate the multiplicative subgroup of $\mathbb{F}_{q^n}$. These are very important in finite fields. There are interesting questions one can ask that don't seem to have a clear analogy in classical number theory.

Comment: One example that comes to mind: can one show there are infinitely many degrees for which the number of primitive polynomials with trace 0 is close to the number of primitive polynomials with trace 1? Has a comparative number theory flavor :) (my experiments show that primitives tend to prefer to have trace 1 rather than 0, in a sense similar to the Chebyshev bias for primes congruent to 3 mod 4 vs 1 mod 4).

Comment: By *trace of a polynomial* you mean? The negative of the coefficient of degree $n-1$ term?

Comment: Hi, yes that's what I meant. The trace function (which essentially gives that coefficient) being another fundamental object in finite fields. An expression in terms of Gauss sums for this difference (primitives with trace 0 vs 1) gives an upper bound roughly about $\frac{\phi(q^n-1)}{q^n -1}q^{n/2}$ by Weil's bound and triangle inequality. But there are indeed cases where the difference is smaller.

Comment: My next suggestion would have been to look at related character sums :-) I gotta go run a math contest for junior high kids. I hope to be able to return to this ... if only I knew when.

Comment: Have a good day Jyrki and thanks for the thoughts on this. I think I'll have to learn a lot before the fun can start... :)